# Jquery- Set select option back to his default option

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu, default

I have several drop down lists (select option) in my site. What I'm trying to achieve is that when user selects an option from one dropdown list, and then selects an option from second drop down list, the first one will get back to default.

Any suggestions?

This is what i have tried with jQuery:

*I marked I caps where I couldn't find the right command.. I tried several methods but no good.. Commands that haven't worked list :*

```
$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());
this.find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

What I tried - Working but the change value command doesn't work.. It loop through all selects jQuery:

```
$('select').change(function(){
   x =  $(this).attr('id');

   $('select').each(function () {
    _id = $(this).attr('id');
          if(_id != x)
          {
            **CHANGE BEACK TO DEFAULT COMMAND** -COULDT FIND IY
            }

});



});
```

HTML :

```
<select id="1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><select id="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><select id="3">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><select id="4">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I read your question three times and still don't know what it is that you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/fw82vrw0/)

Matt's solution works for the situation you presented, but here is a more robust way that will take into account if you have a default option set via the `selected` attribute on an option.

ex. `<option selected="selected">Opel</option>`

```
// Reset the other select elements
// When we choose something
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).siblings().prop('selectedIndex', function(index) {
        // Search for a default option
        var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option[selected]');        
        if($selectedOption.length)
            return $selectedOption.index();

        // If there is no default, just reset to the first option
        return 0;
    });

    // Do what you want with the value
    // var value = $(this).val();
    // console.log(value);
});
```

```js
// Reset the other select elements
// When we choose something
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).siblings().prop('selectedIndex', function(index) {
        // Search for a default option
        var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option[selected]');        
        if($selectedOption.length)
            return $selectedOption.index();
        
        // If there is no default, just reset to the first option
        return 0;
    });
    
    // Do what you want with the value
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

Has default value of "Opel":
<br />
<select id="4">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel" selected="selected">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is there any way to find the value of the seleceted option?

Comment: @roim I updated the answer to show how to get the value after resetting the other `select` elements: `var value = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('select').not(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);            
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tj4k8eeq/1/

Comment: This answers the second sentence in OP's first paragraph, this is what i think he's looking for too, from the current description.